# Installation Subversion-1.6.17 in Linux Mandriva - bin folder is not created

Tags: linux, svn

I'm trying to install **SVN** in **Linux**.

Execute commands -

```
./configure --prefix=/subversion --without-apxs --with-apr=/apr/bin/apr-1-config --with-apr-util=/apu/bin/apu-1-config --disable-neon-version-check --with-neon=/neon
...
make
...
make install
...
```

But in the folder `/subversion` created only directories `/lib` and `/include`, not created `/bin`.

**make** command ends with -

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [subversion/svn/svn] Error 1
```

**make install** command ends with -

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [subversion/svn/svn] Error 1
```

Installed successfully -

- apr
- apr-util
- neon

File **sqlite3.c** is added to the folder */sqlite-amalgamation/*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing the "make install" as root, or as a regular user?

Comment: I'm not sure on the specifics of subversion, but it could be that the executable is being moved into one of the standard Linux bin directories on install. You may try checking /usr/local/bin/

Comment: I don't see a point to struggle with installation from source, when it's available in your distribution. http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=subversion&submit=Search+...&system=Mandriva&arch=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is telling you that you are missing a required dependency, the `expat` [XML parsing library](http://expat.sourceforge.net/). No binary will be created because your compilation is unable to complete the linking step.